# MongoConfigurationException when SRV connection string

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-4.6.1

Driver Language - C#

Driver Version - 2.7.0

DB Version - 4.0.0

.NET Framework 4.6.1

Exception message (credentials and server removed)

> The connection string
>   'mongodb+srv://USER:PASS@uat-xxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
>   is not valid.

Code

```
var client = new MongoClient(@"mongodb+srv://USER:PASS@uat-xxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
```

User and password contain no special characters

No connection attempt is made to the server.

However, this works fine if i use the URI version

```
var client = new MongoClient(@"mongodb://USER:PASS@uat-shard-00-00-xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017,uat-shard-00-01-xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017,uat-shard-00-02-xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=UAT-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true");
```

I've tried to decipher the validation rules from [the source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/ec74978f7e827515f29cc96fba0c727828e8df7c/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Configuration/ConnectionString.cs) but it's beyond my regex ability.

The srv connection string looks fine to me and is exactly the same as that presented to me in the Mongo Atlas UI.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I get this with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted to reproduce this using

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://USER:PASS@cluster0-xxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
var dbs = await client.ListDatabaseNames().ToListAsync();
Console.WriteLine(dbs);
```

Which gave me the expected output (2 database names).

My test environment is .NET 4.6.1, LINQPad, and C# Driver 2.7.0.

You can try eliminating the C# Driver (and framework) from the equation by using the Mongo Shell to test. If you're using Mongo Shell version 3.6 or later, you can test the connection with a command similar to

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-xxxx.mongodb.net/test" --username USER
```

That being said, you should be able to contact MongoDB Support for your atlas cluster, using the "Support" link on the left side of the Atlas UI. They should be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction.  We had recently updated the driver.  Deleted all bin and obj directories from the project and rebuilt the solution in Visual Studio and that seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @alexs glad to hear it!